# ddms emulator control disabled

Tags: android, android-emulator, gps, ddms

i am beginner in android development and the problem is that emulator control is disabled on the ddms. I tried to open but i could not find how to open it again? How can i open emulator control? Thank  you for your replies.

Comment: I have the same issue. is it resolved ?

Answer (score 18):

From the DDMS perspective click Window, Show View, Other - then drill down to Android and select Emulator Control. The view should open. If all the inputs are greyed out, then you need to click on the emulator (emulator 5554 probably) in the Devices view to enable input in the Emulator Control view.

Answer (score 3):

For enabling emulator control in DDMS, you have to select a device from the device view

Answer (score 2):

Pick the device process from the device section in DDMS.  Eclipse might stop responding as in my case.  Restart eclipse but keep the emulator running.  When you return to eclipse it will be enabled.